# dplyr mutate grouped data without using exact column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to wirte a function to process multiple similar dataset, here I want to subtract scores obtained by subject in the second interview by scores obtained by the same subject in the previous interview. In all dataset I want to process, interested score will be stored in the second column. Writing for each specific dataset is simple, simply use the exact column name, everything will go fine.

```
d <- a %>% 
    arrange(by_group=interview_date) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(subjectkey) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(score_change = colname_2nd-lag(colname_2nd))
```

But since I need a generic function that can be used to process multiple dataset, I can not use exact column name. So I tried 3 approaches, both of them only altered the last line

Approach#1:

```
dplyr::mutate(score_change = dplyr::vars(2)-lag(dplyr::vars(2)))
```

Approach#2：
Second column name of interested dataset contains a same string ,so I tried

```
dplyr::mutate(score_change = dplyr::vars(matches('string'))-lag(dplyr::vars(matches('string'))))
```

Error messages of the above 2 approaches will be

```
Error in dplyr::vars(2) - lag(dplyr::vars(2)) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Approach#3:

```
dplyr::mutate(score_change = .[[2]]-lag(.[[2]]))
```

Error message:

```
Error: Column `score_change` must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 10880
```

10880 is the row number of my sample dataset, so it look like group_by does not work in this approach

Does anyone know how to make the function perform in the desired way?

Comment: Are the data.frames always imported in the same order of columns?  You could then perhaps name the data.frames the same in each case e.g. col1, lead, lag

Comment: yes this could be an approch, but still I want to learn how to mutate grouped data without using exact column name. This time I can do so by renaming column, but next time I may not be able to do so

Comment: Would you know the name of the second column in each case, but it varies? Or is the only thing you know that you want the second column's change?

Comment: I know the names of the second columns, but it varies. But I also want to know how to deal with the second case you described

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use position of the column names use `cur_data()[[2]]` to refer the 2nd column of the dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

d <- a %>% 
        arrange(interview_date) %>%
        dplyr::group_by(subjectkey) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(score_change = cur_data()[[2]]-lag(cur_data()[[2]]))
```

Also note that `cur_data()` doesn't count the grouped column so if `subjectkey` is first column in your data and `colname_2nd` is the second one you may need to use `cur_data()[[1]]` instead when you `group_by`.

Comment: what is cur_data()? I got error message says no such function

Comment: `cur_data()` is available in `dplyr` 1.0.0 or higher. You need to update your `dplyr` package. Run `install.packages('dplyr')`

Comment: I tried ```dplyr::group_by(cur_data()[[1]]) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(score_change =  cur_data()[[2]]-lag(cur_data()[[2]]))```now it works, but a new column named ```cur_data()[[1]]``` is also added to the result, and value of this column is exactly the same as subjectkey, any idea about why this happens?

Comment: Yes, it will create a column with `cur_data()` if you include it in `group_by`. You can remove them afterwards if not needed. One of `%>% ungroup %>% select(-1)` or `ungroup %>% select(-contains('cur_data'))` should work.